# What is the default font used on WPF MS Ribbon Control?

Tags: wpf, fonts

What is the default font and ForeGround used in Microsoft MS Ribbon Control? Or, what is the font and font ForeGround we see on the Ribbon like that we see on Excel and Wordpad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Segoe UI Symbol at 9 points